# Greater than opertor in javascript is not working inside xslt

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt-1.0

I have an xslt as

```
              <td>
                <div>
                  <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./id"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    var a=1;
                    var b=2;
                    if(a>b)
                      alert("b is small");
                    else
                      alert("a is small");
                  </script>
                </div>
              </td>
```

I am not getting alert message at all. I tried even parseInt but no use. Please give me suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is maybe a javascript error before this code preventing it to run.

Comment: Try to us &lt;instead of <

Comment: I tried if(a &lt; b)   alert("a is small"); else alert("b is small"); but it is not working

Answer (score 4):

Embed the script-code into a [CDATA-section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output)

Example:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  var a=1;
  var b=2;
  if(a>b){alert("b is small");}
  else{alert("a is small");}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: #Dr.Molle Can you please give some example

Comment: I've added an example above